# Can not unlock screen in Loki

Tags: release-loki, greeter

After a fresh install and both `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` of Elementary OS Loki I try to lock and then unlock my laptop.

After the screen is locked, when trying to unlock, screen turns to black and doesn't show me the password prompt to unlock, only the mouse pointer. I hace to restart LightDM every time in order to get a session back.

I'm using a Gateway NV55C Laptop with an Intel HD 4000 graphics card.

**Do you know what the problem is?**

**Do you know a fix for it?**

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with my notebook (Intel Core i5 430M, ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470)

Answer (score 0):

I have this sometimes. It appears as if it's just the screen that's turned off. When I type my password and press enter it turns on and I'm logged in again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the workaround in this link
[Empty desktop after installing 4.1 version](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11993/empty-desktop-after-installing-4-1-version/12015#12015)
The symptoms are not exactly the same but its possible that the root cause is.

Also can you post a logs somewhere, it would be helpful